# Difference between Angular property and Custom CSS Properties in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Could you give an example of usage of CSS Custom Properties

```
--ion-grid-padding
--ion-grid-padding-lg
```

with **Angular**.

Specifically, I do not see a thin difference between `size-sm` and `--ion-grid-padding-lg`?

I do not understand where and in what file I should use custom CSS properties (also, how to use them properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom css properties in the file variable.css, for example:

```
--my-custom-opacity: 0.8;
```

In the css file associated with your page, or in global.css, you can access this property using:

```
.my-css-class {
   opacity: var(--my-custom-opacity);
}
```

Your html elements will be attributed an opacity of 0.8.

If you need to update this property to change on a single page (and stay the same elsewhere), you can update it using the host tag:

```
:host {
   --my-custom-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

In that case, your elements will be attributed an opacity of 0.6 on this page only.

This is an easy way to apply css values at multiple places in your code and update when necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do I add `--ion-grid-padding-lg`?

Comment: This is a property already created for an ionic element with a default value. You can update it by giving an id or css class to the ionic element and in you css:  .ionic-grid-class { --ion-grid-padding-lg: 10px }

Comment: If I need to edit size-sm on `<ion-col>` then I do it like this `<ion-col size-sm="3"`.
So size-sm is not a property I can edit via CSS? What is the difference between `size-sm` and `--ion-grid-padding-lg`?

Comment: Size-sm is an input property of the ion-col component and will update many css properties when updated, and probably other things in the background. You cannot update it via css directly. The css property --ion-grid-padding-lg on the other side is just there to define a css value for the element and might actually have a different value depending on the size-sm property. You can update it via inline css or in an associated css file as I stated above.

Comment: In variable.css
`--ion-grid-padding-lg: 10px;`
In a component's CSS file
`.my-css-class {
   padding: var(--ion-grid-padding-lg);
}`
Is the syntax correct?

Comment: This is only the case for your own custom css (if you want to add one yourself). This css property is already defined by ionic and applied to the ion-col element. What you want to do to update it is to do in your html: <ion-col class="my-ion-col"> and in your css file: .my-ion-col { --ion-grid-padding-lg: 10px }